# Sklearn: How to make an ensemble for two binary classifiers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have two classifiers for a multimedia dataset. One for visual material and one for textual material. I want to combine the predictions of these classifiers to make a final prediction. I have been reading about bagging, boosting and stacking ensembles and all seem useful and I would like to try them. However, I can only seem to find rather theoretical examples for my specific problem, nothing concrete enough for me to understand how to actually implement it (in python with scikit-learn). My two classifiers both use 10 KFold CV with SVM classification. Both outputting a list of `n_samples = 1000` with predictions (either 1's or 0's). Also, I made them both produce a list of probabilities on which the predictions are based, looking like this:

```
 [[ 0.96761819  0.03238181]
 [ 0.96761819  0.03238181]
  ....
 [ 0.96761819  0.03238181]
 [ 0.96761819  0.03238181]]
```

How would I go about combining these in an ensemble. What should I use as input? Ive tried concatenating the label predictions horizontally and input them as features, but with no luck (same for the probabilities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for combining strictly, I recomend using [brew](https://github.com/viisar/brew) because it is built on top of sklearn (meaning that you can use your sklearn classifiers), and, last time I checked, sklearn was good for creating ensembles (Bagging, AdaBoost, RandomForest ...), but not many combining rules were provided for your own custom ensemble (such as hybrid ensembles).

https://github.com/viisar/brew

```
from brew.base import Ensemble
from brew.base import EnsembleClassifier
from brew.combination.combiner import Combiner

# create your Ensemble
clfs = your_list_of_classifiers # [clf1, clf2]
ens = Ensemble(classifiers = clfs)

# create your Combiner
# the rules can be 'majority_vote', 'max', 'min', 'mean' or 'median'
comb = Combiner(rule='mean')

# now create your ensemble classifier
ensemble_clf = EnsembleClassifier(ensemble=ens, combiner=comb)
ensemble_clf.predict(X)
```

Comment: could you tell me how to do this in python,i will clarify to you , i have six feature subset , for each of them i try multiple classifiers , reach to the most suitable algorithm for each one ... my question now how to combine them using ensemble classifier like bagging, adaboost, voting ,etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the ensemble method you want to implement. Have you taken a look at the `sklearn-ensemble` documentation?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble

Comment: Yes I have, but it requires me to provide the classifiers as input, right? I already have the predictions, the outcome of the classifiers. So I was looking for a way to build an ensemble from this. I understand it depends on the ensemble I want to implement, but for now I haven't even able to build a single one.

Comment: Yes, that is the essence of a meta-classifier: using various classifiers to improve the predictions.

If you want to provide the predictions as inputs you'd have to use a simple learning algorithm (a classifier, for instance), not an ensemble method, because you aren't ensembling algorithms.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Would you recommend using ensembling rather than what I'm trying?

Comment: One more question, if that's okay: Would it then make sense to just concatenate my two predicted label lists horizontally? e.g. '[[1 0][1 1]...[0 1][0 1]]' and then throw it in a classifier? Or am I approaching this incorrectly. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Well, it depends again on implementation and structure. But remember that a classifier takes input data and tries to assign them to a class. What class would be a line including all of the predictions?

There's no way to know with certainty which classifier will work best without testing it. I would recommend you to use a graphic tool like Weka or RapidMiner to get an overview of your data and test various classifiers.

Answer (score -3):

There is a classifier called 'VotingClassifier'  in sklearn.ensemble which can be used to club multiple classifiers and the predicted labels will be based on voting from the enlisted classifiers. Here is the example:

Comment: Were is the example ? you answer a 2 years old question, the asker may not need an answer anymore so it should be clear enough to help anyone having similar question